# How to add check box with bulk action like CRUD for multi rows in admin panel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have made simple checkboxes to each row.... but didn't get the logic behind multi or bulk action code...

```
 $output = '
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">  
     <tr>
      <th width="5%">ID</th>
      <th width="25%">Image</th>
      <th width="10%">Page</th>
      <th width="10%">Videolink</th>
      <th width="10%">Title</th>
      <th width="10%">Subtitle</th>
      <th width="10%">Active</th>
      <th width="20%">Action</th>

   </tr>
  ';`
```

here is my admin panel page where I am not getting the checkbox values. which I want on every row.

id. Please check the attached screenshot

[image]

Comment: where your table generator code?

Answer (score 1):

Your tags imply you'll consider an answer using jQuery. That being the case:

1. detect click of 'select all' checkbox/button
2. find all input[type="checkbox"] elements in container/table
3. set checkbox property to 'checked'

I'd like to be more specific, but your code/pictures don't really make the question clear enough to write a more targeted answer.